# Не закрывается мобильное меню bootstrap при клике на router-link

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap4

Есть совершенно [типовой код navbar bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), на мобильных устройствах меню схлопытвается и показывается "бутерброд" с версией мобайл меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё прекрасно работало в классическом asp.net core приложении, а когда создал приложение на vue.js вылез вот какой неприятный глюк: нажимаешь на иконку меню, раскрывается пункт меню, кликаешь любой - происходит переход, но меню не сворачивается, продолжая загораживать добрую треть экрана.

Можно ли как-то это исправить?

Сам код:

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
    <router-link
      to="/Transaction/Create"
      class="nav-brand"
      v-if="isAuthenticated"
    >новая транзакция</router-link>

    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbar1"
      aria-controls="navbar1"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
      <menu-main/>
      <menu-user/>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import MenuMain from '@/components/MenuMain';
import MenuUser from '@/components/MenuUser';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'Navigation',
  components: {
    MenuMain,
    MenuUser,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['isAuthenticated']),
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Прежде всего небольшой совет [Использовать Vue обертку над
>   bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/). Вы используете компоненты вместо чистого bootstrap. А так же избавляет Вас от главной проблемы - Bootstrap делает изменения в `DOM` за которыми Vue приходится постоянно следить. Это может привести к неожиданным ошибкам, а так же сведет на нет все оптимизации Vue заставляя пересчитывать изменения в DOM каждый раз. Вы не должны использовать каких либо библиотек изменяющих `DOM`помимо Vue в иерархии корневого элемента Vue (обычно это элемент с id app)

Что касатеся самого вопроса. Я не уверен как именно у вас реализованно меню, но надеюсь что оно лежит в отдельном компоненте.

Тогда вы можите создать некую переменную например "hide", по умолчанию меню закрыто по этому `true`.

```
data () {
    return {
        hide: true
    }
},
```

А затем в watch следить за изменением $route и закрывать меню:

```
watch: {
    '$route': {
        deep: true,
        handler () {
            this.hide = true;
        }
    }
}
```

В HTML строчку:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Меняете на:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" :class="{ hide }" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Comment: @AK так в итоге мой вариант Вам помог? это решение должно бьыть лучше чем предложенный Вами вариант, хотя бы по тому что нам не нежно каждый раз обращаться к DOM

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Лично мне идея с watch'ами (их у меня и так висит множество) не особо нравится, но думаю, что другим будет полезно, плюсанул.

Comment: C watch'ами вам не придется ставить @click на каждый router-link. а с :calss вам не придется искать в доме элемент при каждом клике.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно проблема действительно такова что в классических приложениях при выборе пункта происходит переходит на другую страницу и всё отрисовывается заново - а в javascript-фреймворках перерисовки страницы стараются избегать.

Я быстро нагуглил [такой вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45434123/5752652) решения проблемы: добавлять к пунктам меню функцию, которая будет закрывать меню.

```
<router-link to="/syllabus 1" @click.native="closeMenu($event)">


   methods: {
      closeMenu($event) {
          $($event.currentTarget).closest('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
      }    
   }
```

Comment: Если кто знает более предпочтительный вариант - пишите, это чисто пример, чтобы был хоть какой-то рабочий вариант. Мне вот например, не нравится, что приходится тащить jQuery для такой операции.